# Is my new motherboard too slow or is the shopkeeper lying?

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop, graphics-card, motherboard

I have a Dell N5110 laptop and recently the motherboard burnt down completely and was termed as not repairable so I replaced the motherboard with another one in one of the local shops.

I got my laptop back now but when I try to start it, it doesn't usually turn on on the first attempt and some times when it turns on, it turns off and turns on back again.

Every time I get on to Windows, I have to start the wireless connections manually using <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, which wasn't the case with my old motherboard, the time also resets itself after each restart. I also feel it is a bit slower. I asked the shopkeeper and he said that the processor also sustained some minor damages which is causing the slow down and is the reason for the laptop not turning on in the first attempt. By turning on, I mean pressing the power button.

Also, the previous board had an Nvidia 525M video card. the new board doesn't have it, can I transfer the card from that board to this one or should I get a board with the card already installed in it?

Comment: Because it is in a working state and when it works, it doesn't need to be changed. It works perfectly on my OS. The question is, what is the cause to the power button not working on the first attempt? If it is the board then I'll replace the board but if it is the CPU, it means more expense.

Answer (score 3):

This "shopkeeper" sounds like he took you for a sucker.  There are quite a few red flags in your post...

The major flag is that laptop CPUs are soldered onto the motherboard, so if he replaced the motherboard, the CPU would have been replaced too.

I would demand your money back, then go shopping for a new laptop.

Comment: I agree, and I want to also mention that the GeForce 525M that you has is better then the integrated graphics you have embedded in the CPU. If he threw that out (without telling you) it isn't right.

Comment: I just replaced the board so he didn't throw it out, the new board didn't have one, I guess. Also to answer your concern Keltari, the processor wasn't replaced at all, nothing except the board was replaced, the processor, RAM and harddisk are the same.

Comment: that is not possible.

Comment: @Keltari: Can you explain why it's not possible? Not all laptop CPUs are soldered-in and non-replaceable (they can be simply [screwed-in](http://www.laptopmag.com/advice/how-to/replace-your-cpu.aspx?version=1&step=4)), so if the new MB has the same socket it should be possible.

Comment: @Karan true, not all CPUs are soldered on.  But its so rare, I would bet it isnt.

Comment: The OP seems to be pretty confident his CPU hasn't been changed. Perhaps he can tell us how he knows for sure. That would help clarify matters instead of assuming it isn't possible.

Comment: In addition, why would the "shopkeeper" not replace a CPU that he "knows" is bad?  Especially since he kept the "bad" CPU and put it on a new motherboard.

Comment: the whole thing sounds fishy.